# What is other way of use Limit function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, limits

How to use `LIMIT` function in SQL Server?

I need  to create a pagination using SQL Server data and I need to fetch the data using `$start` and `$pagesize`.

This is the query used:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Customers 
  LIMIT $start, $pagesize;
```

Comment: be sure to look at answer 1 and 2 in the link in comment above

Comment: Related question: [How does paging work with ROW_NUMBER in SQL Server?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/how-does-paging-work-with-row-number-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query

```
select * from (
SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY az135 desc ) AS RowNum
FROM    ( SELECT     az13 FROM a12 WHERE   (az133 = '**') ) AS RowConstrainedResult )as a WHERE   RowNum >= 10 AND RowNum <= 20
```